# Is the empty set the only possible set for $A$ such that $A=\{x|x\not\in A\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the empty set the only possible set for $A$ such that $A=\{x|x\not\in A\}$?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Did you mean $A=\{x \in B|x\not\in B\}$ ?

Comment: I don't understand why people are even answering as if $\{x\colon x\not \in A\}$ is a set.

Comment: @GitGud: I'm working in NGB where it is a perfectly cromulent class :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complement of $A$, $A^c$ is such that $$A^c = \{x\mid x\notin A\}$$ A set cannot also be its own complement, and we have $A\neq A^c \implies A\neq \{x\mid x \notin A\}$

Comment: The most understandable answer. :-) Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, Who!

Comment: What we do have is $A\cap \{x|x\notin A\} = \varnothing$, (no element in the universal set can be in both $A$ and $A^c$), whereas the union of $A$ and $A^c$ is precisely the universal set. So every element in the universal set is an element of exactly one, and only one, of $A$, $A^c$.  Note that if the set $\{x \mid x\notin A\} = \varnothing,$ then $A$ must be the universal set. And if every element in the universal set is a member of $\{x\mid x\notin A\}$, then $A =\varnothing$.

Answer (score 3):

*Not even* the empty set has that property.

For any set $A$ we can show $A\ne\{x\mid x\notin A\}$. Namely, either $42\in A$ (in which case $42\notin \{x\mid x\notin A\}$), or $42\notin A$ (in which case $42\in \{x\mid x\notin A\}$). In both cases we have found something that is a member of exactly one of the collections, so they're not the same.

Comment: Doug would be happy.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
empty set also doesn't satisfies that condition.